# Should I separate Google Analytics for website & webshop?

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress

I am setting up a website with in addition a webshop, driven by Wordpress. Both are hosted on same server and domain. Except the webshop will also be reachable through mainsiteshop.com which will redirect in DNS settings to mainsite.com/shop/

What is best practice for using Google Analytics? Should I create a property for the main site, and one for the shop? Or can I use just one property?

Comment: It going to be confusing in GA to have users accessing the same page at `mainsiteshop.com/page.html` and `mainsite.com/shop/page.html`.   I'd try to redirect one to the other if possible.

Comment: Yes, before you think about your GA, think about website structure & setup. Not recommended to access one website from 2 different domain as it will produce duplicate content, so have secondary redirecting to the primary. GA: Keep both at one page it will lot easier to view the report and traffic path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have the same tag on your website and web shop, since your web shop falls within your domain, in the /shop/ directory. That way, you won't have to switch Properties when you're examining the flow of users from the website to the shop.

You may consider setting up a separate View, however, just for your web shop. This view will allow you to focus solely on your web shop. (Alternatively, you can set up a segment within your main View, that would only display data on the web shop.)

You mentioned your web shop will technically live on its own URL, and permanently redirect to a directory on your website. You may begin to see that URL show up as a referrer, in which case you will have to exclude it from your reporting as a referrer in your Analytics settings.